# Как ограничить зону видимости глобальной переменной в многофайловой программе

Tags: c

Нужно, что бы var не был виден в main, но виделся и использовался в других файлах.

Когда было сделано как ниже - работало.

```
MAIN.c
#include Header.h
foo1();

Header.h
void foo1(void);
void foo2(void);
void foo3(void);

Variables.h
static int var;

Source.c
#include Header.h
#include Variables.h
foo1(){var++;}
foo2(){var++;}
foo3(){var++;}
```

После изменения как ниже - перестало, при каждом вызове функции var == 0, а вне не определен.

```
MAIN.c
#include Header.h
foo1();

Header.h
void foo1(void);
void foo2(void);
void foo3(void);

Variables.h
static int var;

Source1.c
#include Header.h
#include Variables.h
foo1(){var++;}

Source2.c
#include Header.h
#include Variables.h
foo2(){var++;}

Source3.c
#include Header.h
#include Variables.h
foo3(){var++;}
```

Comment: У вас сейчас в каждом файле своя переменная var; вам надо объявить ее в одном .c файле так же как она сейчас в хеадере, а в самом неадере (в других файлах) как extern

Comment: Не очень понял, объявить в source, а в других source и header как extern. Мне очень бы хотелось, что бы переменные были определены в 1м отдельном файле и были не видимы в других файлах, кроме определенных мной.

Comment: ну так добавьте в Variables.h к объявлению слово extern. А саму переменную объявите в одном из .c файлов, любом, который с ней работает

Comment: Иных менее "костыльных" способов нет? Это моя первая многофайловая программа и я все равно путаюсь в этом... Хотел что бы первичное объявление в header было, от этого вообще что то меняется? Сейчас подумал и вроде бы нет.

Comment: Ни в первом, ни во втором варианте нет никакой "глобальной переменной". Переменная в обоих случаях статическая, т.е. никаком боком не глобальная. Поэтому ничего в первом враианте "работать" не могло.

Comment: Сейчас решил продолжить работу по первому варианту и вполне работает.

Comment: "Работает" и "не работает" - бессмысленные словосочетания. Что там у вас "работает" тут никому не ясно. Но обсуждению не подлежит тот фат, что никакой глобальной переменной у вас нет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А какой смысл в вашем пожелании?

Вы хотите использовать в `main()` свою переменную с именем `var` или что? Просто **смысл** глобальной переменной именно в этом - быть видимой везде, во всех файлах. Так что поясните, что именно вы хотите, а то пока что требования у вас противоречивые... Может, можно было бы использовать статическую переменную в функции - например,

**Variables.h**

```
int* getVar();
```

**Variables.c**

```
int* getVar()
{
    static int var;
    return &var;
}
```

**SourceN.c**

```
#include "Header.h"
#include "Variables.h"

void fooN(){ (*getVar())++; }
```

Но чтобы понять, подходит ли вам это решение - нужно понимать, что вы хотите. Глобальные переменные вообще лучше не использовать...

И еще - по первому варианту у вас в `main()` своя переменная `var`, в `Source` - своя. Как и во втором - в каждом файле - своя переменная. Это - *не* глобальная переменная, она просто видна везде на уровне файла, но в каждом файле она своя.

Comment: Я хотел, что бы переменная была видна только в указанных мною source файлах. Например в source видима, в main нет.

Comment: Вопрос один - зачем?

Comment: Вопрос изначально был не корректен и вызван не пониманием принципа включения файлов и обеспечения модульности.  Удалить вопрос не могу, но смысла он не несет никакого.